How can I send my own token for my middleware authenticate method and apiKey the server that i request?
I have middleware.js file like this ;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const secretKey = 'asdASD';

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log('Authorization Header:', authHeader);
    if (!authHeader) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "No authorization header provided" });
    }
    
    const tokenParts = authHeader.split(' ');

    
    if (tokenParts[0] !== 'Bearer' || tokenParts.length !== 2) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid authorization header format" });
    }

    const token = tokenParts[1];

    console.log(token);
    console.log('Decoded Token:', jwt.decode(token));
    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('JWT Verification Error:', err);
            let errorMessage = 'Invalid token';
            if (err instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) {
                errorMessage = 'Token has expired';
            } else if (err instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
                errorMessage = 'Invalid token';
            }
            return res.status(403).json({ error: errorMessage });
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
    
}

module.exports = {
    authenticateToken,
};

And I use it in my login method ;
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    const { rows } = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [req.body.username]);
    const user = rows[0]; 
    
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    
    const isMatch = req.body.password === user.password;
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
    } else {
      const token = jwt.sign({ username: req.body.username, user_id: user.user_id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, secretKey);
      
      return res.status(200).json({ token, verified: true, message: "Login successful", user_id: user.user_id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin });
    }

    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occured." });
  }
});

When I try to use it in another post method, I get 403 Forbidden error cause of jwt malformed. Because I need to use

'Authorization': Bearer ${apiKey}
in axios.post headers. So when I use authenticateToken method in this I send wrong token for middleware.js.

app.post('/api/admin-dashboard/devices/firewalls/:deviceId/configure-address', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const { deviceIp, apiKey, config } = req.body;
  const { deviceId } = req.params;
  const path = 'firewall/address';

  const isAdmin = req.user.isAdmin; 

  try {

    if(isAdmin) {
      const requestId = await dbQueries.storeConfigurationRequest({
        device_id: deviceId, 
        config: config,
        path: path,
        status: 'pending'
      })

    res.json({ message: "Address configuration request submitted, pending admin approval." });
    }

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send('Failed to submit configuration request');
  }
});

I need to get "isAdmin" value from correct token and I also need to hold

'Authorization': Bearer ${apiKey}

for post request. I need suggestions and help for this problem. I am open to change anything with new ideas.
